# Pie chart scrolling beyond the screen in aChartEngine

Tags: android, android-widget, achartengine

If we do the scrolling in pie chart, the pie chart is scrolling beyond the screen both vertically and horizontally.
I am also getting a black screen at particular point in time.

Any solution for this?
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling". Do you mean pan or zoom?

Comment: @Dan I also am facing same issue that user is currently able to pan the chart outside the screen. Is there any way to disable the user to that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this if you don't want enable the scrolling through the chart:

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
```

Also you can let the user scroll the chart and add the zoom buttons, so user can return to the 1:1 view:

```
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
```

**renderer* is the DefaultRenderer wich you add the series.

Comment: renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);

Comment: Actually piechart having long labels.Inorder  to view that user will zoom and scroll the chart.So I need both functionalities to do this.  Otherwise labels should be shown fully in single line or in multiline without zooming but with scrolling. Is that possible?